# Alterar chaves de array javascript

Tags: php, javascript

minha função javaScript enviar meus dados por input hidden para o PHP dessa forma:

```
$('<input/>').attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "produto"+ contador + "[]").val(formData).appendTo(row);
    $('<input/>').attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "produto"+ contador + "[]").val(form_data["amount"]).appendTo(row);
    contador++;
```

Só que no PHP esta chegando dessa forma;

[image: Array]

Como eu posso alterar para ao invés de aparecer

```
[0] => Novo Produto
[1] => 2
```

Aparecer assim:

```
[Produto] => Novo Produto
[Quantidade => 2
```

Como eu faço?

Comment: Tente assim: `$('<input/>').attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "produto"+ contador + "[][Produto]").val(formData).appendTo(row);` e o mesmo para `amount`: `$('<input/>').attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "produto"+ contador + "[][Quantidade]").val(form_data["amount"]).appendTo(row);`

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Vou colocar como resposta, pode servir para outros usuários

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altere seu código especificando qual o nome da chave:

```
$('<input/>').attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "produto"+ contador + "[][Produto]").val(formData).appendTo(row);
$('<input/>').attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "produto"+ contador + "[][Quantidade]").val(form_data["amount"]).appendTo(row);
```